# Fastlane Gym Xcode Build Linker 'don't know how to convert branch' crash

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, fastlane, fastlane-gym

When building our C++ Game project for iOS with the latest Fastlane version and Xcode 8.3.3 and Xcode 9.0.1, we're facing linker errors / crashes.

Fastlane Gym Call:

```
fastlane gym --scheme "TowerDuel-mobile-Release-Distribution-Live-Beta" --export_method "app-store" --configuration "DistributionLiveBeta"
```

Logs:

```
**▸ Compiling BackButtonReceiver.cpp
▸ Compiling FirebaseTestLayer.cpp
▸ Linking TowerDuel-mobile

❌  ld: don't know how to convert branch instruction f1bd87d4 referencing __ZdlPv.island to bx in '__GLOBAL__sub_I_OnEventHeal.cpp' from /Users/Max/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TowerDuel-dsejjkbvgengpngaqrfokeoaquvx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/TowerDuel-mobile-Release-Distribution-Live-Beta/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/TowerDuel.build/DistributionLiveBeta-iphoneos/TowerDuel-mobile.build/Objects-normal/armv7/TowerDuel-mobile_lto.o for architecture armv7



❌  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


▸ Linking TowerDuel-mobile
** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
Ld /Users/Max/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TowerDuel-dsejjkbvgengpngaqrfokeoaquvx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/TowerDuel-mobile-Release-Distribution-Live-Beta/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/TowerDuel.build/DistributionLiveBeta-iphoneos/TowerDuel-mobile.build/Objects-normal/armv7/TowerDuel-mobile normal armv7
(1 failure)
[02:10:38]: Exit status: 65
[02:10:38]: 
[02:10:38]: Maybe the error shown is caused by using the wrong version of Xcode
[02:10:38]: Found multiple versions of Xcode in '/Applications/'
[02:10:38]: Make sure you selected the right version for your project
[02:10:38]: This build process was executed using '/Applications/Xcode.app'
[02:10:38]: If you want to update your Xcode path, either
[02:10:38]: 
[02:10:38]: - Specify the Xcode version in your Fastfile
[02:10:38]: ▸ xcversion(version: "8.1") # Selects Xcode 8.1.0
[02:10:38]: 
[02:10:38]: - Specify an absolute path to your Xcode installation in your Fastfile
[02:10:38]: ▸ xcode_select "/Applications/Xcode8.app"
[02:10:38]: 
[02:10:38]: - Manually update the path using
[02:10:38]: ▸ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app
[02:10:38]: 
**
```

Comment: This is not an issue with `fastlane` itself, but rather a problem with linking the project. Have you tried `xcodebuild` itself directly on your application from the command line? Are you able to build the project from within Xcode without an issue? Does it build with both Xcode 9 and 8.3.3?